# I have a drawing pad, and want to overlay an image that is just an outline (so the image is transparent except for some black lines).

Tags: image, canvas, drawing, overlay, draw

I have it so that you can draw under the image, but you must start drawing outside of the image border and move under the image. So you can't start right on the image. How do I fix this?

My html is just:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<img id="html5" src="http://i.imgur.com/Wpx3Vum.png" style="position:absolute;left:100px;top:15px;" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two canvas elements instead:

- Put two canvas elements [on top of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008635/html5-canvas-element-multiple-layers/3008863#3008863)
- [Draw the image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you want to superimpose on the top canvas
- Add [mouse event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047877/seamless-drawing-in-multiple-canvas) to the top canvas
- When drawing read the positions from top canvas but draw the lines to the bottom one using the bottom canvas' context

(links just meant as examples)

An example of this could be including a simple basic draw function:

### [Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Y8DxA/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="cont">
    <canvas id="canvasBottom" width=400 height=400></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvasTop" width=400 height=400></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#cont {
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #777;
    height:400px;
    }
#cont > canvas {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    cursor:crosshair;
    }
```

**JavaScript:**

Load and set the image to top layer:

```
var img = new Image,
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvasBottom'),
    canvasTop = document.getElementById('canvasTop'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    ctxMouse = canvasTop.getContext('2d');

img.onload = setup;
img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/HNiER0v.png';

ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0, 100, 255)';

function setup() {
    ctxMouse.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
}
```

Handle mouse:

```
var px, py, isDown = false;

canvasTop.onmousedown = function (e) {
    var pos = getXY(e);
    px = pos.x;
    py = pos.y;
    isDown = true;
}

canvasTop.onmouseup = function () {
    isDown = false;
}

canvasTop.onmousemove = function (e) {
    if (isDown) {
        var pos = getXY(e);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(px, py);
        ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
        ctx.stroke();
        px = pos.x;
        py = pos.y;
    }
}

function getXY(e) {
    var rect = canvasTop.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: e.clientX - rect.left,
        y: e.clientY - rect.top
    };
}
```

As you can see you can now draw behind the initial drawing:

[image: Fancy image]

(Now, if that is not a master piece than I don't know what a master piece is..!)

Comment: this was great, thanks a lot! you made it very easily understandable, I really appreciate it.

Comment: So this worked perfectly, the only thing is that when I add the image, the image is very large. I can't figure out how to scale it... just setting img.width = 200 doesn't do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3285918 you can use the extended parameters of drawImage like  for example: `ctxMouse.drawImage(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`